# how to have a auto increment filed in mongodb as we have in mysql

Tags: mongodb, auto-increment

I want to have auto increment filed in mongodb when  inserted a new document to the collection i want a unique identifier for the model other than object Id  ie,
i have a model as shown below

```
{
    /*_id:Number,*/
    authorId : Number,
    isDeletedAuthor:Number,
    name: {
      fullName: {
        firstName : String,
        lastName : String,
      }
    }


  }
```

how to place the value of authorId with unique integer value on inserting document looking for simple way with a example

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a separate collection to track the ID and an atomic `$inc` operation to increment it.

```
 var sequenceDocument = db.counters.findAndModify({
      query:{_id: sequenceName },
      update: {$inc:{sequence_value:1}},
      new:true
   });
```

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-atomic-operations/ and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm

Comment: The link died, perfect example of a bad answer.

Comment: @Madmenyo looks like it's alive now, but redirects to a different article that isn't relevant to the question.